# When rolling 3 dice, is the probability of rolling the same number three times the same as rolling three different numbers?

Tags: probability, dice

Is the outcome 111 as probable as e.g. 123?

Comment: Does the order of the numbers matter?

Comment: no, it doesn't matter

Comment: Have you tried what happens with two dice?

Comment: we are arguing about it here.. a friend says the probability is 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/6 for 3 different numbers - and 1/6 + 1/6 + 1/6 with the same number ... or something like that :D

Comment: @MarkBennet While a good way to see how the calculations work, the result doesn't necessarily generalise. Just think about seven dice.

Comment: @Arthur There are no ways of choosing seven different elements from a set of six. If you express the result in the right way, then it will generalise.

Answer (score 3):

**No,** if you are interested in `111` vs. *any* outcome with three different numbers.

The probability of getting same outcome thrice is $(\frac{1}{6})^3 $ but that of getting 3 different numbers is $(\frac{1}{6}).(1-\frac{1}{6}).(1-\frac{2}{6})$ i.e. (Probability of getting say 1) * (Probability of not getting 1) * (Probability of not getting 1 AND the number you got on second throw) .

**Yes,** if you are interested in `111` vs the *specific* outcome `123`. If you want the probability of outcomes specifically 1,2,3  then it is same as 1,1,1 because probability of getting 1 = probability of getting 2 = probability of getting 3 = $(\frac{1}{6})$. Therefore the result is same as that of three simultaneous 1s = $(\frac{1}{6})^3$.

Comment: Nicely done, Hope you don't mind my small clarifying edits.

Comment: @BruceET Of course not.

Answer (score 0):

No. To see this, consider that for the first, second, and third die to be the same, you can only roll a $1$ on all three dice. On the other hand, consider that the first die you roll can be $1,2,3$, that the second die can be either of the two remaining numbers, and that the third die must be the last number. The actual probabilities are $\frac1{6^3}=\frac1{216}$ for the same and $\frac1{6^3}*3!=\frac1{36}$ for the three different dice.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the words "rolling the same number three times"?

What do you mean by the words "rolling three different numbers"?

If "rolling the same number three times" means "choose a number, then roll it three times in a row" then the probability of success is $\left(\frac16\right)^3.$ If it means merely that the three rolls should all be the same as each other, then the probability is much higher: $\left(\frac16\right)^2.$

If "rolling three different numbers" means "choose three numbers $x, y, z,$
all different, and roll $x$, then roll $y$, then roll $z$"
the probability again is $\left(\frac16\right)^3.$
If it means "choose three numbers $x, y, z,$
all different, and roll all three numbers, but it does not matter
which of them you roll first or which you roll last"
the the probability rises to 
$3! \times\left(\frac16\right)^3 = \left(\frac16\right)^2.$
If it means, "roll three times, and and the end of the three rolls
none of the numbers you rolled should be the same as either of the others,"
then the probability is even higher: $\frac56\times\frac23.$

In summary,
the probability of rolling $1,1,1$ is the same as the probability
of rolling $1,$ then $2,$ then $3.$
But that is not what most people would think you mean when you
ask about "rolling the same number three times" or
"rolling three different numbers."